# iOS dismiss UIAlertController in response to event

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I have a situation where I want to present a `UIAlertController` in order to wait for an event (asynchronous request for data from third party) to finish before showing my main `ViewController` to the user to interact with.

Once the asynchronous code finishes, then I want to dismiss the `UIAlertController`. I know that normally UIAlertControllers are setup with a button to dismiss it, which is input from the user. I am wondering if what I want to do (dismiss with an event instead of user input) is possible?

So far, I tried to show the `UIAlertController`, and then wait in a while loop checking a boolean for when the event occurs:

```
var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Please wait", message: "Retrieving data", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

// dataLoadingDone is the boolean to check   
while (!dataLoadingDone) {

}

self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

This gives a warning

Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!

and does not dismiss the UIAlertController. I also tried `alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)` instead of `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)`, but this doesn't get rid of the `UIAlertController` either.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a *while loop* but a `didSet` observer for your `dataLoadingDone` property. Thereby, you may try something similar to the following code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var dismissAlertClosure: (() -> Void)?
    var dataLoadingDone = false {
        didSet {
            if dataLoadingDone == true {
                dismissAlertClosure?()
            }
        }
    }


    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Please wait", message: "Retrieving data", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        // Set the dismiss closure to perform later with a reference to alert
        dismissAlertClosure = {
            alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }

        // Set boolValue to true in 5 seconds in order to simulate your asynchronous request completion
        var dispatchTime: dispatch_time_t = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(5.0 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
        dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), { self.dataLoadingDone = true })
    }

}
```

Comment: hmmm...I think I'm a bit confused about your example. Could you include some more comments to explain what you are doing? In particular, I'm confused about when the closure is getting called, and the didSet part as well

Answer (score 0):

Another user (matt) gave what I'm pretty sure is the correct answer, but he removed it, so I'm going to answer it. Just wanted to give credit (though he seems pretty reputable anyways).

What he wrote is that my UIAlertController presentation was not finished before I tried to dismiss it, so I got that error. I changed my code to the following:

```
// check if I need to wait at all
if (!dataLoadingDone) {
        var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Please wait", message: "Retrieving data", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in
            // moved waiting and dismissal of UIAlertController to inside completion handler
            while (!self.dataLoadingDone) {

            }

            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        })
    }
```

I moved the waiting and dismissal inside the completion handler of the presentViewController call, so that I know the presenting is done before dismissing. Also, I check if I need to wait at all with the first if statement, because otherwise another issue occurs if the while loop never does anything.

I'm not 100% sure yet, because my boolean is actually never false at the moment (the data retrieval happens really quickly). However, I have reason to believe it will take longer later on in my app development, so I will update the answer here once I have that.

EDIT: another user who previously posted an answer (Aaron Golden) was also correct about while loop blocking. I had thought that the while loop shares processing time with other events, but apparently not (or at least not enough time). Therefore, the above while loop DOES NOT work

Comment: The while loop is unnecessary and just wasting CPU cycles. Why not hold a reference to the UIAlertController and dismiss it wherever you set self.dataLoadingDone to true?

Comment: Yes, I actually realized that too. What I essentially wanted to do was wait for an asynchronous request to finish, and was using the while loop to wait. However, this wasn't necessary as its actually just waiting anyways without the while loop = )

What I ended up doing (will update the answer at some point) was register a notification through NSNotificationCenter to respond to the event. This way, I don't need the boolean either.