# Can we dismiss system generated alerts programmatically using private api's

Tags: ios, iphone-privateapi, alerts

I want to dismiss system generated alerts. Application developed is enterprise version, so I don't have to worry about Apple review.

I want this to work without jailbreak.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please checkout this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31857137/how-to-programmatically-dismiss-uialertcontroller-without-any-buttons

Comment: Please read question first, I am asking about system generated alerts.

Comment: Do you mean something like Push permission, or location permission alert?

Comment: Any system level alert, like when we initiate call using URL schemes and it shows an alert prompt for confirmation

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about alerts for URL schemes then you can't do anything about them. These alerts are being displayed by the SpringBoard. When you're calling any URL scheme it gets forwarded to the SpringBoard. It parses it and from there does the necessary thing. For phone calls it actually checks that and displays special alert to request permission from user to do the call.

Comment: Is there any way using private frameworks to handle this.

Comment: @Jas_meet, the alert is from a different process. You can't do anything about it. It's like trying to hide UIAlertController being displayed by a different iOS application. But in this case it's not just any application but the SpringBoard itself.